# Slicing an Array and producing an object from it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-5

I have an array and it looks as follow:

```
[
    {
        "DT_RowId": "row_4758",
        "companies": {
            "id": 23,
            "email": null,
            "name": "test"
        },
        "USERS": {
            "UserId": 23
        }
    },.....
]
```

How do I slice it and get only "companies": and the result as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 23,
        "email": null,
        "name": "test"
    },.....
]
```

to clear some issues I have added the function in which I'm using data.map

```
fn.loadData = function (data) {
                    var dataKeys = Object.keys(data);
                 console.log(data)// 'data' is an object
                    console.log(data.map(x => x.companies)) ///data.map not a function error
                    var infiniteList = document.getElementById('infinite-list');

                    infiniteList.delegate = {
                        createItemContent: function (i) {
                            return ons._util.createElement(
                                '<ons-list-item modifier="chevron" tappable>' + data[dataKeys[i]].name + '</ons-list-item>'
                            );
                        },
                        countItems: function () {
                            return Object.keys(data).length;
                        }
                    };

                    infiniteList.refresh();
                }
```

Comment: `array.map(m => m.companies)`.

Comment: @Liam thanks! but I'm getting "data.map is not a function"  data is the array

Comment: Well [`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a function. So <shrug>

Comment: @yopipe the problem is not in the example you showed us ...

Comment: @adirabargil thanks for your comment, I have added the entire function to provide more context

Answer (score 1):

as comments told you to do:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "DT_RowId": "row_4758",
        "companies": {
            "id": 23,
            "email": null,
            "name": "test"
        },
        "USERS": {
            "UserId": 23
        }
    },
        {
        "DT_RowId": "row_3758",
        "companies": {
            "id": 24,
            "email": null,
            "name": "test3"
        },
        "USERS": {
            "UserId": 24
        }
    },]
    console.log(data.map(obj=>obj.companies))
```

Comment: I have added the entire function to provide more context

Comment: but what data prints"?

Comment: console.log(data);  its returns an Object

Comment: but how the object look like?

Comment: @adril it looks as follow: [
    {
        "DT_RowId": "row_4758",
        "companies": {
            "id": 23,
            "email": null,
            "name": "test"
        },
        "USERS": {
            "UserId": 23
        }
    },.....
]

Comment: And please post it in the question and edit it, i am talking about what you get from the `console.log(data)`

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
const newArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < companyArray.length; i++) {
       newArray.push(companyArray[i].companies);
}
```

Thanks, everyone